# Перенос базы MS SQL в Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

Всем привет! Имеется Windows 8 с установленными 1С Деньги и MS SQL Server. Возникла необходимость БД в Azure. Все делаю по мануалам с оф сайта
Предварительно создал виртуальную машину с windows server, SQL Server и базу данных sql, все работают как показано на скриншоте.
[image: ресурсы]
На определенном этапе у меня почему то не отображается имя виртуальной машины. Что я делаю не так? Какая именно машина должна быть?
[image: подключение]

Answer (score 3):

В SQL Azure есть два варианта хостинга базы.

- SQL Azure - отдельный экземпляр SQL, которым управляет сам Azure. Для него не нужна виртуалка, вы платите просто за доступ к готовому серверу.
- Virtual Machine с установленным на нее SQL Server - машина должна быть создана из шаблона с предустановленным SQL. Который вам вручную надо обновлять и мониторить.

Визард, который вы запустили, приспособлен для второго варианта. У вас же создана обычная VM, без SQL Server и база SQL Azure из первого варианта.

Вам надо

- или пересоздать VM с испольованием предустановленного Win + SQL - стоит выбрать, если вы на ней собираетесь хостить, например, сам 1C
- или удалить виртуалку (если вы на ней ничего не собираетесь хостить) и использовать визард для миграции в SQL Azure:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создал SQL Server 2014 Enterprise on Windows Server 2012 R2, но выбрать в SSMS ее все равно не получается, может уже проще базу вручную перенести?